# frequency multiplier

Tags: frequency, multiplier

I need to generate a sine wave with freq of the order of GHz. I have generated a sine wave of around 20-30 MHz. So I am thinking of using a frequency multiplier circuit. Any ideas how I should proceed ?

Comment: frequency multiplier's can't multiply that far easily. perhaps use a gigahertz clock and a filter?

Comment: What you need is a Phase Locked Loop. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop  Texas Instruments and Analog devices make PLL ICs for your convenience.

Comment: Even with PLL cascaded ring oscillator VCO can generally get you around 1-2 GHz, 10 GHz is way to large.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the product ranges by Analog Devices, Maxim or TI (analog.com, maximintegrated.com or ti.com) for RF PLL synthesisers. Buy one, or better still buy an evaluation board with a chip on.

It's very unlikely that a frequency multiplier will do what you want, whatever you want.